# Android ListView onItemClickListener error

Tags: android

I am trying to make my program respond to an item click and this my code

```
list.getOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(NumbersActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But i get this error

> Error:(43, 13) error: method getOnItemClickListener in class
>   AdapterView cannot be applied to given types; required: no
>   arguments found:  reason: actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length where T is a type-variable: T
>   extends Adapter declared in class AdapterView

Comment: you need to set it instead of get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `setOnItemClickListener` event.

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     //code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use:

```
    ListView list = getListView();
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
            // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
            // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
      }
   });
```

also import:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

Comment: @Mohamed Hisham if the answer worked..mark it as accepted by clicking the tick sign of the answer